# How to print Key-Value Pairs in nested dictionaries by value string

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary with several dictionaries inside of it, and I would like to print the content of one specific key searching by a string value

The dictionary

```
dict1 = {1:{'Nombre' : 'Tom Cruise', 'Año': '1963', 'Sexo' : 'Masculino', 'Peliculas': 'Mission Impossible, Interview with the vampire' },
         2:{'Nombre': 'Brad Pitt', 'Año' : '1974', 'Sexo': 'Masculino', 'Peliculas': 'Interview with the Vampire, Fight Club'},
         3:{'Nombre': 'Antonio Banderas', 'Año' : '1976', 'Sexo': 'Masculino', 'Peliculas': 'The Mask of Zorro, Desperado'}
        }
```

What I want is to capture an string using input and use that string to search for the dictionary information where there is a match. I tried using several dict methods including .items(), but it didn't do what I needed it to do (By user input get an actor's name and print all the information about that entry).

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code!

Comment: The question would be clearer if you gave an example of an input and what the output should be in that case.

Comment: I tried using .items(), fromkeys() and values(), but none of them did what i wanted to do. I haven't done  too many things with dictionries and I'm jut trying stuff out but right now I can't think of anything else.  Sorry I'm a newbie and thanks for your help!                                                                    
 `elif selector == '3':
        actor = input('Introduzca el nombre del actor/ de la actriz que quere mostrar ')
        print(dict1.items(actor))`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to filter in your multiple dictionaries. This function can help to understand the dictionary logic.

```
dict1 = {1: {'Nombre': 'Tom Cruise', 'Año': '1963', 'Sexo': 'Masculino',
             'Peliculas': 'Mission Impossible, Interview with the vampire'},
         2: {'Nombre': 'Brad Pitt', 'Año': '1974', 'Sexo': 'Masculino',
             'Peliculas': 'Interview with the Vampire, Fight Club'},
         3: {'Nombre': 'Antonio Banderas', 'Año': '1976', 'Sexo': 'Masculino',
             'Peliculas': 'The Mask of Zorro, Desperado'}
         }


def searchInDict(searching):
    for keyMain in dict1:
        for keyChild in dict1[keyMain]:
            if searching in dict1[keyMain][keyChild]:
                return dict1[keyMain][keyChild], keyMain, keyChild


findingVal, key1, key2 = searchInDict("Zorro")
print("Finding Value is '{}': in key '{}' and subKey '{}' field".format(findingVal, key1, key2))
```

That's a solution but I propose a solution for your dictionary, but a regular and quality way is not that for dictionary logic. You must create a class, object list can hold your data. For your situation:

```
class MyObj:
    def __init__(self, id, nombre, ano, sexo, peliculas):
        self.id = id
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.ano = ano
        self.sexo = sexo
        self.peliculas = peliculas

    def search(self, searching):
        if searching in self.peliculas:
            return self
        return None


dict1 = [MyObj(1, 'Tom Cruise', '1963', 'Masculino', 'Mission Impossible, Interview with the vampire'),
         MyObj(2, 'Brad Pitt', '1974', 'Masculino', 'Interview with the Vampire, Fight Club'),
         MyObj(3, 'Antonio Banderas''1976', 'Masculino', 'The Mask of Zorro, Desperado')]


def searchInDict(searching):
    for obj in dict1:
        searchResult = obj.search(searching)
        if searchResult:
            return searchResult


res = searchInDict("Zorro")
print("Finding Value is '{}': in key '{}'  in peliculas".format(res.peliculas, res.id))
```

Answer (score 0):

It will probably be easiest if you make another dictionary where the keys are the names, and then you can just do a lookup from that dictionary.  For example:

```
dict2 = {d['Nombre']:d for d in dict1.values()}

print(dict2['Tom Cruise'])
```

gives:

```
{'Nombre': 'Tom Cruise', 'Año': '1963', 'Sexo': 'Masculino', 'Peliculas': 'Mission Impossible, Interview with the vampire'}
```

Note that in this case I have not bothered to remove the name itself from the sub-dictionary. You could do this by doing:

```
dict2 = {d['Nombre']:d.copy() for d in dict1.values()}
for d in dict2.values():
    del d["Nombre"]
```

where here we are using copies of the sub-dictionaries (rather than direct references to them) so as not to interfere with the original dictionary.

Then you can do for example:

```
print(dict2['Tom Cruise'])
```

giving:

```
{'Año': '1963', 'Sexo': 'Masculino', 'Peliculas': 'Mission Impossible, Interview with the vampire'}
```

If the key used for lookup is to derive from user input, you can use the `input` function, for example:

```
name = input('What is the name? ')
print(dict2[name])
```